# How to run an dataform workflow from airflow composer in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, dataform

I have the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from google.cloud.dataform_v1beta1 import WorkflowInvocation

from airflow import models
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataform import (
    DataformCancelWorkflowInvocationOperator,
    DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator,
    DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator,
    DataformGetCompilationResultOperator,
    DataformGetWorkflowInvocationOperator
)


with models.DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,  # Override to match your needs
    tags=['dataform'],
) as dag:

    create_compilation_result = DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator(
        task_id="create_compilation_result",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        compilation_result={
            "git_commitish": GIT_COMMITISH,
        },
    )

    create_workflow_invocation = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
        
        task_id='create_workflow_invocation',
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        workflow_invocation={
            "compilation_result": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}"
        },
        
    )


create_compilation_result >> create_workflow_invocation
```

and it throws this error:
ERROR - Unable to retrieve connection from secrets backend (CloudSecretManagerBackend). Checking subsequent secrets backend.

I have attempted to follow the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-composer, but it seems that there is an issue with my Airflow Composer configuration. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to add this in my code but, it doesn´t help:

```
gcp_conn_id='my_gcp_connection'
```